# Ajax page, facebook's FB.init() causes all ajax requests to happen twice?

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook

I have an ajax driven web app that uses some of the features of the facebook connect api.

Once i've initiated facebook connect with:

```
FB.init("my_key_here");
```

using

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://static.ak.connect.facebook.com/js/api_lib/v0.4/FeatureLoader.js.php"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://static.ak.connect.facebook.com/connect.php/en_GB"></script>
```

All ajax reuest's i make are being called twice. If i comment out the FB.init() line everything returns to normal and the ajax requests are only made once.

Is this a common problem? Any ideas for preventing this double-ajax problem?

Answer (score 0):

My dear it is happening because you are connecting with facebook twice.
try to remove the first line

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://static.ak.connect.facebook.com/js/api_lib/v0.4/FeatureLoader.js.php">
```

I hope it will work